# OpenSourec PHP and MySQL based POS application

Tags: looking-for-a-script, web-applications, recommendations, post

I was looking OpenSource PHP and MySQL based POS(point of sail) web application. easy to use for users and flexible for customizing the future.

Which alive project you recommend?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

OpenERP has a POS built in as well as other business applications such as a CRM http://www.openerp.com/

They have a free community edition which you can download